# Using B-coefficients from logit in a linear prediction equation (Stata 13)

Tags: stata, logit

This is probably basic, but the answer has eluded me so far...

In Stata, if one runs the `logit` command, coefficient values are given.

For the variables with p-values <0.05, I want to include them in a *linear prediction equation* for clinicians to use in the field to predict disease (with a known sensitivity and specificity). However, the coefficients outputted from logit cannot be used in a linear formula.

How can one transform these in Stata into coefficients that can be used in a formula like
 E.g., Your score = some_constant + coefficient x (1 if weight loss occurred; 0 if none)

Comment: What do you mean by _score_? If you mean log odds, that is what logistic regression predicts. Also, if you have some predictors not significant at a conventional level, then at best you need to rerun a model with just your intended predictors, although many would be very queasy about that. (Not clear to me that using Stata makes any difference to the statistical questions, but if you're asking for Stata code that is off-topic here.)

Comment: Not sure if "score" is the right word, but I was referring to when, after doing logit, and then running rocomp (with the "detail" option) one gets a column called "cut-point". I am trying to replicate how each of those cut-point values was calculated for each patient but am unable to figure out the formula. In linear regression it would just be the value of each significant predictor*B-coeffecient + constant - correct?